# How to know what implementation of graphics 2d my spring boot project is using

Tags: spring, spring-boot

As stated in the title. I have a project that uses Graphics 2d. While debugging I am able to see that my project uses SunGraphics2d implementation of the graphics 2d abstract class. How do I find out without going into debug mode and moreover how do I find the same about other abstract classes?

As an example, hibernate implementation of JPA interface is provided by default in spring. How to find what implementation is provided in spring by default and how to change the default.

Comment: You mean, like using reflection? Are you asking how in general to figure out the concrete type of an object?

Comment: I have added an example for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Spring/Spring boot doesn't manage anything related to graphics. So you don't have any spring related tools to help you out here.

In a plain java world, reflection is probably the best choice then